# Firebase avoid illegal access to Storage

Tags: android, security, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm building an Android app and am currently integrating Google Firebase. I've already set up a database. Since my app will download sensitive images via Google Firebase storage, access to these images must only be allowed for authorized users. In the Firebase database I manually added the URLs of the images from the storage (I would have preferred to do it automatically, but I don't know how).

What is the best way to give different users access to different graphics in the Firebase storage?

Thanks!

Edit: Iam allready read that: [Google Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices) but renaming images in difficult to guess names, doesn't seem to be the safest solution

Comment: Renaming images with randomly generated base-64 names of length 30 will take 64^30 or 10^54 tries for a brute force attack. This is a  insanely huge number. Other than that did you see in the doc that you can define security criteria from fire-base console in a JSON like format.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user upload the image or you through the app?
I can suggest this if so:

Have a private image button.

in onCreate()

```
 imageButton =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibImageSelect);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Request);

        }
    });
```

outside a method body:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Gallery_Request && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageButton.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

On your button click

```
StorageReference upload = storageReference.child("what you want");
Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri); 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    UploadTask filePath = upload.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment()).putBytes(data);
 filePath.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

 filePath.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

@Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


     DatabaseReference newPost = mref.push(); //this generates a random unique key 
replace with your own if you want, since you already got your own structure



    newPost.child("image").setValue(imageUri.getLastPathSegment()); 
//set image name so can use this to download the image

    }
     });
```

you could have a "status" child in each node of the data, then when downloading the images you loop through all the nodes, check if the status is what you want to to be. Then get the image download key.

for downloading images:

loop through the nodes and children, get the img url,

```
    String ref = "image folder in firebase storage/" + imgurl;
                storageRef.child(ref).getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                        // Use the bytes to display the image
                          final  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id...);

iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.i("error", exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this solution does not prevent a Bruteforce attack that allows hackers to guess the filenames. Your solution does not protects the data as not yet unauthorized access. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Edit: The pricing for 20 GB / Month is about 256 times higher for the Database than for the Storage, so I would definitly prefere to use a the Storage. :) https://firebase.google.com/pricing/